# Accumulator variables and its use

Tags: sas

I am trying to test how accumulator variables work and I created the following program.

```
data numbers;
input n;
cards;
10
20
40

50
;

data newnums;
 infile numbers;
  input tens;
 count+tens;
run;

proc print data=newnums;
run;
```

I purposely put blank rows.  However besides that I thought that the program would execute.

I want to figure out the last value of the variable count, but I cannot... may I have some help please?

Answer (score 2):

you have multiple things in your code, which you need to change.

1. missing numeric value is represented as `.` character
2. data set is referenced using `set` statement not `infile`
3. accumulator variable you are talking about is `sum` statement, it retains the value when you have missing value and more on sum statement in the link below.

[Difference between SUM statement and sum variable in SAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677244/difference-between-sum-statement-and-sum-variable-in-sas)

```
data numbers;
input n;
cards;
10
20
40
.
50
;

data newnums;
set numbers;
count+n;
run;

proc print data=newnums;
run;
```

Edit1: if you had something below you will get missing value by using truncover

```
   data numbers;
   infile datalines truncover;
   input n;
  cards;
  10
  20
  40

  50

  ;
```

Comment: I think you mean Sum not some.

Comment: Ah, that is why it did not work.  Thank you.  The blank was to experiment if SAS would automatically understand that as a missing value.  It turns out that it does not. Thanks!

Comment: @hyg17 below thing will also work.   data numbers;
  infile datalines truncover;
input n;
cards;
10
20
40

50
70
;